# @OneToMany is not fetching for existing childs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I have code to archieve `@ManyToOne` relation using Hibernate. I have two classes `Package` and `Address`. In `Address` i would like to have unique entries where every address is somehow different from other. Then I have `Package` which is using it.

```
@Entity
public class Address {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  String street_with_number;
  String city;
  String region;
  //...
}

@Entity 
public class Package {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  String eshopId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="destination_address_id")
  private Address destination_address;

  //...
}
```

Then I have JpaRepository to create repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PackageRepository extends JpaRepository<Package, Long> {
   //...
  }
```

Afterwards I am using it injected in REST controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class RestController {
  private PackageRepository packageRepository;

  @Inject
  public void setRepository(PackageRepository packageRepository) {
    this.packageRepository = packageRepository;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<?> addPack(@RequestBody Package pack) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(packageRepository.save(pack), HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

Then using HTTP REST I send json like this

```
{
   "eshopId" : 1,
   "destination_address": {
       "street_with_number": "string",
       "city": "string",
       "region": "string"
   }
}
```

Which creates one entry in table `Package` and one in Address with OK also destination_address_id pointing to right `Address.id`. Then I send the same JSON again and hibernate creates new `Address` same as that one before, it is not reusing it.

I would like hibernate to check if address exists and if yes, it would not create new row in table `Address` but use that one which is already there. Is that somehow simply possible? This behavior creates two duplicate lines (only ID is different) which is not what I want. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check whether this address is already defined by yourself. There is no Hibernate mechanism that could do it for you.

I would advise you creating an `AddressService` with method lets say `getOrCreate()`  method that would check if there is an address with passed data or should it be created. It is some kind of a bussiness rule for you so presenting an additional layer between controllers and repositories feels like a good idea.